# Differences between Microsoft-STL and GNU-STL

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, unordered-map, std-pair

As you know, you can't write such code in C++:

```cpp
struct Test
{
    Test _this;
};
```

But this is quite possible

```cpp
struct Test
{
    Test* _this;
};
```

That's when I got this error while writing the following code

```cpp
error: 'std::pair<_T1, _T2>::second' has incomplete type
       _T2 second
```

```cpp
struct Test
{
    std::unordered_map<int, Test> dictionary;
};
```

I thought that the msvc implementation of `std::pair` uses pointers for storage.

It's true? If not, what is the difference between the implementations and what is the reason for this?

https://godbolt.org/z/vafxjW5vd

Comment: The linked question explains the arkane prohibition about incomplete types used as template parameters (the same thing applies to `unordered_map` as to `vector`), so this boils down to implementation-defined behavior. My opinion is that this is a defect in the standard.

Comment: I expect the error message to be a bit longer; does it mention `_T2 = Test` or a similar Test-related type?

Comment: @MSalters No. Only such a chain of errors
https://gist.github.com/uselessgoddess/c2df049ce55184abfb7981641dd25ca3

Comment: @dodickgod: The actual `pair` is in the very first line. You might note that compared to `std::unordered_map<int, Test>`, that `pair` adds a `const` to `int`.